# Measure extending length defined on all sets

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure

It is well-known that assuming the axiom of choice, there is no measure defined on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that is translation-invariant (the Vitali example).

It is also well-known that Solovay constructed models of ZF where all subsets of the reals are measurable.

I would like to know if the existence of a measure defined on all subsets of the reals giving to any interval its length as measure and the axiom of choice are incompatible.

Comment: What you are looking for is real-valued measurable cardinals. Short answer: If you accept certain large cardinals, then they are compatible.

Comment: Compatible or incompatible? If they are compatible assuming large cardinals hypotheses, then they are also compatible without assuming them, right?

Comment: @Plop Well... assuming the large cardinals themselves are compatible with ZFC. Here is the precise statement: ZFC proves such a measure exists if and only if a real-valued-measurable cardinal exists. So the existence of such a measure is consistent if and only if the existence of an RVM is consistent. (And as a side note, an RVM is consistent if and only if a measurable cardinal is consistent.)

Comment: (Side side note... while we’re being mindful of consistency strength, the Solovay result requires an inaccessible.)